# Exponential weight tensor in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to write my own layer in Keras where I need to multiply an input tensor by a weight tensor with exponential decay of a trainable value. I was planning on creating the value as a weight then "somehow" expand it.

In python, I will just do this:

```
d = 0.9
window = 6
w = np.array([pow(d, window-j) for j in range(window)])
w = w / w.sum()
```

Output:

```
In [63]: w
Out[63]:
array([0.12602255, 0.14002506, 0.1555834 , 0.17287044, 0.19207827,
       0.21342029])
```

I can see there is `tf.while_loop` which might help, but how do I call tensorflow from Keras?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I've got it, this seems to compile.

```
    # expand the kernel to the size of x
    w = [K.pow(self.kernel, self.kernel_size-j) for j in range(self.kernel_size)]
    w = K.concatenate(w)
    # normalise
    w = w / K.sum(w)
    w = K.expand_dims(w)
    print(K.get_value(w))
    w = K.tile(w, (batch_size, 1, self.rank))
```